# Writing to file with a block, can't get newline to work

Tags: ruby

This one is escaping me (no pun intended).

This first method looks exactly how I want it, only I want to write it to a file.

```
def write_dir_two
  Dir.chdir("/vagrant/TestRails/Music")
    Dir.glob('*') do |file|
     if File.ftype(file) == "directory"
       puts Dir.entries(file)
     end
   end
end
```

Now I can't get the newline to work.  I've tried interpolation, creating a "separator" variable, i.e. `separator = "\n"`, and a few other tricks but it's a no go.  Seems so easy a task and have done it in other situations.  I left all my non-working solutions out but basically I am trying to do something like this - `music.write(Dir.entries("#{file}\n"))`. In other words each file has its own line.  I also tried `file + "\n"`, which also failed.

```
 def write_dir_one
   music = File.new("music_2", 'w')
     Dir.chdir("/vagrant/TestRails/Music")
     Dir.glob('*') do |file|
       if File.ftype(file) == "directory"
         music.write(Dir.entries(file))
       end
     end
 end
```

`puts` just does a great job formatting it to the screen.

edit: I didn't realize I could use `file.puts` instead of `file.write`.  This works but I'll leave it open for the time being if anyone else has a different, better way.

Comment: `file.puts` IS the better way. Also "it failed" is a terrible problem description. Failed __how__?

Comment: It sounds like the new line was just in the wrong place. How about `music.write("#{Dir.entries(file)}\n")`

Comment: @sergio - yes, you are right, bad problem descriptor, it was failing with a syntax error.

Comment: @Puhlze, no I get back a comma delimited listing with that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Dir#entries`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Dir.html#method-c-entries) returns an array of all files in the directory specified, so doing `Dir.entries("#{file}\n")` fails because you don't have a directory with that name with a newline at the end. The reason [`File#write`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/IO.html#method-i-write) doesn't work, is because it simply calls `to_s` on a non-string to convert it to a string before outputting it and [`File#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) works because it specifically states

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

So, if you wanted to do this without using `puts`, you could just call:

```
music.write(Dir.entries(file).join("\n"))
```

Comment: thank you for that explanation.  What confused me is I've used newlines and arrays but it was iterating with the each method. I just tested writing out an `array` to file using `each` and the shovel operator and yes it does serve up the newline `def write_dir_three
  ["abc", "def", "ghi"].each do |letters|
    @music << "#{letters}\n"
  end
end`